# Laptop keyboard issue – some of the keys don't work

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I have a problem with built-in keyboard. I use Acer V3 GT 572G with installed Ubuntu 14.04 + KDE. Problem exists from the first day of usage (I got it only few days).

**Problem:** it happens that some of the keys don't work. Always the same keys are affected (left ctrl, backspace,i,o) and few additional which sometimes work and sometimes don't (some of the numbers from the top of the keyboard). Problem exists only with built-in keyboard, USB keyboard works fine. Problem occurs in most cases after log ut, but sometimes it cannot be predicted; I get an impression that it's related with the position of the laptop, but I am not able to confirm it with absolute certainty.

In the beginning reboot helped, currently I need to restart the laptop more than 1 time to 'fix' it.

**Question:** Can you help me? Should I do some more test, what should I check?

Comment: It's very common for laptops. And the problem is really frustrating. Your affected keys are damaged. That's why they work sometimes and sometimes not. Using a usb keyboard is the only solution I know. If you have warranty, please contact the dealer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything works with a USB keyboard, it is definitely a hardware issue.  The first thing you should try is to remove the keyboard.  Consult your manual or Acer's website for support on how to do so.  Once it is removed, used canned air and blow air in between the keys.  This may dislodge some debris that might be preventing the keyboard from working properly.  Reattach the keybaord's ribbon cable to the motherboard and test if it works normally.  If it does not, then you need to replace the keyboard, as some part of it is broken.  You should be able to get a replacement from Acer.  If it does work normally, then put it back in the case and close it up.  If it stops working in the case, then it could be the case is flexing the keyboard enough to cause an issue.  If thats the problem, then you would have an issue thats harder to fix.  Acer would be able to replace the case, probably at cost if its not under warranty.

Comment: Thank you @Keltari. I will contact with Acer. I received this new laptop 3 days ago, so it can be done under warranty. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Replacing keyboard most likely fix the issue? or could there be a problem other than OS and keyboard, like for example mother board?

Answer (score 6):

No. First check your keyboard booting up your laptop to BIOS. 
If it would work well than your hardware is OK.

Then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

on terminal and choose appropriate keybord Acer V3 should be on the list.

Regards,
Boda

Comment: This fixed the issue on my Asus Zenbook ux501vw laptop. The problem was driving me crazy for a few months now. Thank you so much.